# Good sample references for TGA, DSC and DTA thermal analysis

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am trying to estimate kinetic parameters for my liquid decomposition using thermal analysis. After doing a literature survey, I have decided to use the following -

1. thermogravimetry ([TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermogravimetric_analysis))
2. differential scanning calorimetry ([DSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_scanning_calorimetry))
3. differential thermal analysis ([DTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_thermal_analysis))

Each method will be tried with 3 different constant heating rates. My expected output from this analysis is

1. If multiple steps are taking place

2. prefactor $A$ and activation energy $E_a$ ([Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation)) for each step
3. Reaction model for my process.

And products (my products will be in gaseous form) from these will be analyzed using FT-IR spectroscopy to support my conclusions in case of multi-step kinetics. The problem is  I gave one sample for DSC to a 3rd party company but I am unsure about the accuracy given by the company. What I decided was to give them a known sample whose DSC, DTA, and TGA results are common and fairly complex but known properly, so I can test their method of doing.

If anyone could suggest any common materials which will be available in any chemistry labs whose thermal analysis output I can use as reference it would be very helpful.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S My liquid decomposition will be accompanied by

1. Mass loss
2. Heat release (Intially endothermicity as the solution will be in water and then exothermicity)

Comment: I am puzzled by the proposed course of action. You selected three techniques where you perhaps do not have expertise and you want to test the accuracy of a  third party company by sending them substances that have been well characterized by others. How will you know if they are acceptably accurate?

Comment: A well managed/certified lab routinely checks its instruments with traceable references to meet the standards in the field ([a listing:](https://www.mt.com/ch/en/home/applications/Application_Browse_Laboratory_Analytics/Application_Browse_thermal_analysis/specific-heat-capacity-measurement.html#SpecificHeatCapacity_4) ISO 11357-1, ISO 11357-4, DIN 53765, DIN 51007-1 or ASTM E1269). Cheap and easy (compared to indium) for DSC is sublimed benzoic acid (or others listed [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244024511_Certified_reference_materials_for_thermal_analysis)), but what after?

Comment: It might be more efficient to ask them to display their expertise recording these data for you, e.g., an accreditation, ongoing collaborations with clients other than you, publications, etc.

Comment: @EdV So my thinking was that if they provide same results as the known substances then I can be sure that they are doing the process right. What do you think can be a more better procedure?

Comment: @Buttonwood Thank you for your valuable inputs, so I am a researcher in a university (IIT Bombay) and all these analytical techniques are run by PhD students, so it will be a little tricky to ask them about their expertise directly as I am heavily dependent on them for characterization.  So that's why I thought of taking this politically correct route.  If you could suggest some alternative so as to how I can proceed, I would be grateful.

Comment: I think the suggestions by @Buttonwood are better. The issue with “same results” is how same is same? Frankly, if I was the third party analysts, I would be wondering why I was being sent some simple test samples. Is it because the customer does not trust me or is it a trick of some sort, i.e., a mixture designed to trip me up? By the way, I have not voted at all. Best of success whatever you decide!

Comment: I copy and paste Ed V comment

Comment: @obiwan Continuation in the chatroom [The Periodic Table](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58805470#58805470).